# Binary Search Code error can not be find

Tags: c++, binary-search

The below code can not get the correct answer, but I do not know which part is wrong.
Its logic looks correct, it can not run out the correct answer

```
 /*binary search*/
    int binary_search(const vector<int> &a,int x) {
    long left = 0;
    int mid;
    long right=a.size()-1;
//write your code here
    while (a[left]<a[right]){
         mid=a[left+(right-left)/2];
         if (a[mid]==x){
            return mid;
         }
         else if (a[mid]>x){
            right=mid-1;
         }
         else{
            left=mid+1;
         }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop should be conditioned by `left <= right`.
Also `mid` should be `mid = (left + right)/2;`

Comment: Thank you so much. I was stuck in this code for hours. Every time when I checked the code, I assumed it is what I thought. Thank you so much!!!